# Removing gnome panel to the right on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I accidentally added a panel by right clicking on the bottom tool bar and clicking add panel.  I then tried to delete this, but, the option does not appear when right clicking.

I have looked in .gnome and a number of other configuration files, to see if I can remove this, but, I have not had any luck doing so.

Any suggestions.  I would like to just remove the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Easily fixed by removing three lines

```
panel_0
panel_1
panel_2
```

at the bottom of `~/.gconf/apps/panel/general/%gconf.xml` and restarting my machine.